# how to sort this Nested Data by the number of scores > 90?

Tags: python, sorting, nested-lists

```
gradebooks_a = [[['Alice', 95], ['Troy', 92]],
                [['Charles', 100], ['James', 89], ['Bryn', 59]],
                [['Karren', 97], ['Nancy', 96], ['Astha', 92], ['Jack', 74]]]
```

How to sort this Nested Data by the number of scores > 90? Thank you.

expected output like this:

```
[[['Charles', 100], ['James', 89], ['Bryn', 59]],                # only 1 score above 90
 [['Alice', 95], ['Troy', 92]],                                  # 2 scores above 90
 [['Karren', 97], ['Nancy', 96], ['Astha', 92], ['Jack', 74]]]   # 3 score above 90
```

Comment: Hello. Would you mind showing us your code first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sorted` with a `key` function that receives each list of `(student, grade)` pairs and sorts according to the number of grades that are `> 90`:

```
sorted(gradebooks_a, key=lambda grades_list: sum(grade > 90
                                                 for _, grade in grades_list))
```

We use unpacking while iterating (`for _, grade`) to get a bit more readable code (by giving the second element the name "grade") instead of using indexes. We could use the even more explicit `for student, grade` but that would trigger some linters for not using the `student` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom function as `key` for [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html):

```
out = sorted(gradebooks_a, key=lambda lst: sum([e[1]>90 for e in lst]))
```

explanation:

For each sublist, identify elements where the second item is greater than 90 and count them using `sum`.

output:

```
[[['Charles', 100], ['James', 89], ['Bryn', 59]],
 [['Alice', 95], ['Troy', 92]],
 [['Karren', 97], ['Nancy', 96], ['Astha', 92], ['Jack', 74]]]
```